# Change color of textview in listview?

Tags: android, listview

After I have a small list in a listview how do I go through and change the color of any text matching a string? They will always be the same textview. Do I have to do anything custom to do this or just loop through the listview?

Comment: on which basis you want to change the color of the textview

Comment: only when the textview call it , R.id.sec , has the text of "open" turn it green

Comment: that means when you click the item, then textview should the color, right?

Answer (score 0):

use this to have different color

```
TextView tv = new TextView(xx);
SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder("your string");
text.setspan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
startIndex, len,
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setspan(new ForegrounColorSpan(Color.GREEN),
startIndex,endIndex,
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(text);
```

and use   [fromHTML(String )](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) method for Styles

if you want to get the index of a specified string use `indexOf("your string")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a custom list View than you have to inflate it and after that you can setTextColor(Color.parse("#ffffff")); 
or you can take reference from this 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html
Thanks